# check ModelState errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

if I'm using

```
 ModelState.AddModelError("", "error");
```

later I assign multiple errors.
on later stage I want to determine if ModelState contains any error, so I check that condition and based on that to process further?

Update:
 How can I check if ModelState contains any added error

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to check length of ModelState Errors collection

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true` if there are no errors, otherwise `false` if there are errors

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite understand the question but If you want to know if your model is valid you just check the `IsValid` property of ModelState. Like this:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //Stuff happening
}
```

Comment: nope, I want check custom validation inside posted action and add ModelState.AddModelError(); How can I check if ModelState contains any added error?

Comment: You check the ModelStat for the key of your custom error. like this: 
`ModelState["YourErrorKey"].Errors.Count > 0`. Note that you have to add it like this:  `ModelState.AddModelError("YourErrorKey", "YourErrorMessage")`. ModelState Interprets the key as a property of the model and invalidates it. Not quite sure if you should be doing that. If you want to associate your error with an existing property give it the key that matches the property name.